# Updating data from Firebase Realtime Database ReactJs using hooks

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Anytime the list updates, it forms another array that adds to the previous array, how can I make it to return just one array with the updated information

below is the code

```
useEffect(() => {
    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + '/messages/').orderByChild('createdAt').on('value', function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
            const id = userSnapshot.key;
            const userData = userSnapshot.val();
            setId(id);
            messages.push(userData);
        });
    });

    setMessages(messages);

}, [messages])
```

**usage in body**

```
<ul>
    {messages.map(function(item){
         return (<li key={id}>{item.displayName}: {item.text}</li>)
       })}
</ul>
```

when the list updates once, it returns two more lists, so the new list becomes very very long

Comment: i think it is because of the .push(), is there any alternative to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + '/messages/').orderByChild('createdAt').on('value', function(snapshot) {
    messages = []; // clear existing messages
    snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        const id = userSnapshot.key;
        const userData = userSnapshot.val();
        setId(id);
        messages.push(userData);
    });
    setMessages(messages);
});
```

The changes in here:

- Clear the `messages` array before adding the updated items to it.
- Now call `setMessages` *inside* the callback, to ensure it gets called when the latest data from the database is in `messages`.

Comment: thanks so much for your feedback, it worked, since this is jsx, it worked when i used ```const messages = [ ]; ```

Answer (score 1):

If your messages is a state variable you should never ever change it directly,
what you should do is something like

```
const newMessages = Array.from(messages);
snap.forEach(message => newMessages.push(message))
setMessages(newMessages);
```

But of course is the snap is containing ALL your messages then you can just initialize newMessages as an empty array